# I cannot generated pdf using set of pdfs attached

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pylatex

I have tried several ways to generate a pdf using pyLatex by attaching several pdfs.
my code is as follows in the python file.

```
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Command, Figure, SubFigure
from pylatex.utils import italic, NoEscape

latex_document = '120.tex'
with open(latex_document) as file:
   tex= file.read()

doc = Document('basic')
doc.append(NoEscape(tex))
doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
```

Part of my tex file is as follows.

```
\begin{document} 
\section{test}

\begin{center} 
\chappdf[short title]{chapter title}[page specification]{root/67.pdf}
\includegraphics[frame,page=1,width=17cm,height=25cm,keepaspectratio]{root/67.pdf} 
\newpage 
\includegraphics[frame,page=2,width=17cm,height=25cm,keepaspectratio]{root/67.pdf} 
\newpage 
\includegraphics[frame,page=3,width=17cm,height=25cm,keepaspectratio]{root/67.pdf} 
\newpage 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

part of my current output.

[image: generated pdf. Only the issues are with attached pdfs]

The problem which O faced was the output is raw as below. Can someone help me with this? Do I have to use specific packages to do this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you by any chance did not include the `graphicx` package?  Add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I have used it.But, still not working

Comment: Can you provide the full generated doc. There is no preamble here. Where should chappdf come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `graphicx` is missing.  You should include the package

```
doc = Document('basic')
doc.append(NoEscape(tex))
doc.packages.append(Package('graphicx')) # <- add this 
doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
```

Also, the line

```
\begin{document}
```

and

```
\end{document}
```

are redundant in `120.tex`, since `pylatex` added these lines for you.  You can look at the content of `basic.tex` generated to see the generated file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked!!! :D